# ASP.Net MVC Validation with Entity Framework and POCO

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, poco

I have a question relating to best practices on validation using MVC and POCO. From what I can tell, the best practice is to have a ViewModel that mirrors the POCO and then use something like AutoMapper to parse the ViewModel to the POCO after it (the view model) is validated.

That's all well and good, but I'm wondering if there are any problems with inheriting from the POCO and over ridding only properties I wish to validate in the View Model?

POCO:

```
public partial class Sector
    {
        public virtual int SectorId { get; set; }

        public virtual string Name { get; set; }
    }
```

My ViewModel might look like this:

```
public class SectorDTO : Sector
    {
         [Required]
         [StringLength(10)]
         public override string Name {get; set;}
    }
```

**UPDATE**

This solution ended up not working, mostly due to the way my business layer and data layer's are setup. My solution was instead to create a ViewModel that contained a DTO with all the validation, and then use AutoMapper to change the object back to the POCO type.

Comment: Seems pretty reasonable to me. I'd say if it compiles and works from front to back, then go for it

Comment: This solution ended up not working.

Comment: Your updated solution is what I also do in your case. Also for validation your may want to try http://fluentvalidation.codeplex.com/.

Answer (score 0):

I did like below:

```
public partial class SectorMetaData
{
    [Required(ErrorMessage="Required Filed")]
    public int SectorId{ get; set;}
    [Required(ErrorMessage="Required Filed")]
    public string Name{get; set;}

}

[MetadataType(typeof(SectorMetaData))]
public partial class Sector
{
    public int SectorId{ get; set;}
    public string Name{get; set;}
}
```

This class should be same namespace as POCO class.
Hope this helps!